# ¿Cómo puedo forzar a que se redireccione HTTP a HTTPS en Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat, https

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se redireccione de `HTTP` a `HTTPS` con `Tomcat` 9?
Tengo configurado el server.xml así

```
  <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->

  <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />

  <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
     SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
     library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
     AprLifecycleListener.
     Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
     the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
  -->
 <Connector port="443"
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"

      maxThreads="200"
     scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"

 >
  <SSLHostConfig certificateVerification="none" honorCipherOrder="true" 
  protocols="TLSv1.2" >
    <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="C:\Program 
  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\mercado.jks"
                 certificateKeystorePassword="123456"
               certificateKeyAlias="server"
                 type="RSA" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
  </Connector>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La configuración es si es la misma para todos los apaches desde la versión 6, tienes que primero activar el protocolo https, y luego a las peticiones que ingresen por el puerto http redirigirlas al puerto que tienes configurado en https.

Basicamente tienes que dejar el server.xml de esta manera :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="tuKeystoreLuegoDeCrearlo" keystorePass="PasswordKeystore"/>
```

Te dejo el link de la configuracion de https , puede que los atributos sean diferentes en esta version que el ejemplo que te copie : [COmo configurar ssl apache tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: sorry, mi error jeje, debe redireccionar al puerto que configuras para https como dice en el texto arriba , pero de igual manera corrigo en el xml.

Comment: Te comparto como esta el server.xml Gracias.

Comment: Ya te funciona el https ? antes de el redirect debe funcionar cuando accedas a https://localhost:443

Comment: Si , ya pude acceder al https

Comment: y cuando ingresas solamente a http://localhost , que te sale ? , o a http://localhost:80